# C# WPF Copy Control Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I want to programmatically copy the control tree to a different Grid column and I want to change the P1 in some control-names with P2,P3,P4 for each player so I have 4 similar blocks for showing information abount each player.

The data ist set that way currently so I would just would need to replace the player id:

```
    public void ReadPlayer(Player player) {
        GetControl<Label>(player, "lbl", "Points").Content = String.Format("{0} / 8", player.Points);
        GetControl<Slider>(player, "sld", "Points").Value = player.Points;

        GetControl<TextBox>(player, "txt", "PositionX").Text = player.PosX + "";
        GetControl<TextBox>(player, "txt", "PositionY").Text = player.PosY + "";
        GetControl<TextBox>(player, "txt", "PositionZ").Text = player.PosZ + "";

    }
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="Player 1" Name="grpP1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <GroupBox Header="Points" Height="122" Margin="6,6,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Height="28" Margin="6,0" Name="lblP1Points" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="199" Content="0 / 8" />
                        <Slider Height="34" Margin="6,34,6,0" Name="sldP1Points" VerticalAlignment="Top" SmallChange="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="8" TickPlacement="Both" />
                        <CheckBox Content="Freeze" Height="16" Margin="6,74,6,0" Name="chkP1Points" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Position" Height="121" Margin="6,134,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="62" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="X" Height="28" Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="19" />
                        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="6,9,6,0" Name="txtP1PositionX" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <CheckBox Content="Freeze" Height="20" Margin="0,12,0,0" Name="chkP1PositionX" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="64" Grid.Column="2" />

                        <Label Content="Y" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="19" />
                        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="6,39,6,0" Name="txtP1PositionY" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <CheckBox Content="Freeze" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,41,0,0" Name="chkP1PositionY" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Grid.Column="2" />

                        <Label Content="Z" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="19" />
                        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="6,68,6,0" Name="txtP1PositionZ" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <CheckBox Content="Freeze" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,70,0,0" Name="chkP1PositionZ" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Grid.Column="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
```

Full code see here: https://github.com/SciLor/MashedTrainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying control trees in WPF is not a good approach.

You should stick to MVVM paradigm, 
define the view model class for the data, and use data templates, styles and data  bindings to build the views.

So you should have a data template for the player class, that will act as a view and know how to display the player, and use data binding to bind to player's properties.

When you put a player, or a collection of players in a list control, as its content property, wpf will be able to render them all.

There are plenty of resources on the topic on the web, for starters you could take a look at [this simple MVVM example](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html) and [data binding overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @Schnulli, I've added a couple of links, but feel free to google for more, there are tons of articles on those topics. Good luck!